# How to access element id and other attributes using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have JavaScript method which acts when a particular class (mcb) of forms are submitted:

```
function BindCloseMessage() {
    $(".mcb").submit(function(event) {
        alert("closing..."); //Here I want to get the id of form
        event.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

In place of alert call, I need to access the id of form whose submit is called. How can I do it? Even better will be the tip for accessing any attribute...

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the id of the form being submitted will be

```
this.id
```

or in jQuery

```
$(this).attr('id') //although why type the extra letters?
```

Comment: Additionally `$` would be called, that would create a new jQuery object of `this` and then its `attr` method would be called.

Comment: indeed, but i thought that was obvious;)

Answer (score 4):

```
$(".mcb").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).attr("id"); // Returns FORM ID
});
```

You can learn more about jQuery's attribute-methods at http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes